# TikZ graphs in sectioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, sectioning

I need a large family of  objects of the following (for MWE reasons) simplified type .

```
%  \section{
 Whatever description for  $F_{q
 \raisebox{-.1cm}{\tikz[scale=.25] {
 \draw [red,double] (1,0) -- (0,1) ;
  \draw [blue,double, ] (0,0) -- (1,1) ;
   \draw [violet,double] (2,0) -- (1,1) ;
    \draw [green,double, ] (1,0) -- (2,1) ;
 }}r}$
%  }

%  \subsection{
 Whatever description for  $F_{q
 \raisebox{-.1cm}{\tikz[scale=.25] {
 \draw [red,double] (1,0) -- (0,1) ;
  \draw [blue,double, ] (0,0) -- (1,1) ;
 }}r}$
%  }
```

[image]

If I uncomment these lines, thus putting them in (sub)sections, I get errors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%openin 
\begin{document}

    \section{
 Whatever description for  $F_{q
 \raisebox{-.1cm}{\tikz[scale=.25] {
 \draw [red,double] (1,0) -- (0,1) ;
  \draw [blue,double, ] (0,0) -- (1,1) ;
   \draw [violet,double] (2,0) -- (1,1) ;
    \draw [green,double, ] (1,0) -- (2,1) ;
 }}r}$
    }

    \subsection{ 
 Whatever description for  $F_{q
 \raisebox{-.1cm}{\tikz[scale=.25] {
 \draw [red,double] (1,0) -- (0,1) ;
  \draw [blue,double, ] (0,0) -- (1,1) ; 
 }}r}$
     }

 \end{document}
```

How to type them correctly, so that they can appear in the headings (and TOC). The latter seems to be the problem:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{ Whatever description for $F_{q \unhbox \voidb@x \let \reserved@d =[\def \par }$ }}{1}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a command that generates the picture and precede it in headlines, captions etc. by `\protect`. The latter command takes care that the protected command is not expanded too early.

```
\newcommand\xyz{...}
...
\section{... \protect\xyz ...}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\qrbvgr
 {q
 \raisebox{-.1cm}{\tikz[scale=.25] {
 \draw [red,double] (1,0) -- (0,1) ;
  \draw [blue,double, ] (0,0) -- (1,1) ;
   \draw [violet,double] (2,0) -- (1,1) ;
    \draw [green,double, ] (1,0) -- (2,1) ;
 }}r}
\newcommand\qrbr
{q
 \raisebox{-.1cm}{\tikz[scale=.25] {
 \draw [red,double] (1,0) -- (0,1) ;
  \draw [blue,double, ] (0,0) -- (1,1) ;
 }}r}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

  \section{
 Whatever description for  $F_{\protect\qrbvgr}$
  }

  \subsection{
 Whatever description for  $F_{\protect\qrbr}$
  }
\end{document}
```